# Script to reset scale of Smart Object to 100%

Tags: javascript, resize, photoshop, jsx, photoshop-script

I'm trying to make a script that will take an element on a layer and restore its size to 100%.

This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working on smart objects for some reason. Am I missing something?

```js
try {
  var doc = app.activeDocument;

  var layers = doc.artLayers;

  var size = dialog();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < doc.artLayers.length -1; i++) {

    var activeLayer = doc.artLayers.getByName(doc.artLayers[i].name);

    var orUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;

    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PERCENT;

    activeLayer.resize(size, size, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);

    app.preferences.rulerUnits = orUnits;

  }


} catch (e) {
   alert( e );
}


function dialog() {

  // Dialog box
  var myWindow = new Window("dialog", "Resize Each Layer");

  // Keeps things inline
  myWindow.orientation = "row";

  // Informational text
  myWindow.add("statictext", undefined, "New size ( percentage ):");

  // This is the box where the size is inserted
  var myText = myWindow.add("edittext", undefined, "");
  myText.characters = 5;
  myText.active = true;

  // Ok
  myWindow.add("button", undefined, "OK");
  if (myWindow.show() == 1) return myText.text;

}
```

It doesn't work whenever I try and run it and it does nothing to smart objects at all.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only known to me way of resetting smart object scale is to replace current smart layer with the original temporary psb file (reference file). To do that you first need to find smart object `fileReference` (name of a temporary psb file, it's going to be in temporary folder, you'll find it in layer action descriptor), then place it in your document (using File > Place Embedded), put it to coordinates of the original layer and then remove the original layer. Here's an algorithm:

```
var originalLayer = activeDocument.activeLayer,
    bounds = activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds,
    smartObjectName = getFileReference() //get file reference here

placeLayer(Folder.temp + "/" + smartObjectName) //function to place layer with path to layer as an argument
centerLayerBasedOnBounds(bounds)
originalLayer.remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

layer.resize() is a relative resize, not absolute, so if you tell it to resize by 100%, that won't do anything--you're telling it to resize to its current size.  You'd need to know the current scale to do it that way (which I don't think is exposed).

I don't think there's any way to reset a smart object's scale with a script or recorded action.  Smart objects aren't very well supported by Photoshop's APIs...

Answer (score 1):

By adapting the code I found here I was able to get the unscaled dimensions of the active layer using an ActionReference; https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/how-can-i-capture-a-smart-object-s-original-dimension-via-scripts/td-p/9679328?page=1

```
// works on active layer
function getUnscaledLayerDimensions() {
  var ref = new ActionReference();

  ref.putEnumerated(
    charIDToTypeID("Lyr "),
    charIDToTypeID("Ordn"),
    charIDToTypeID("Trgt")
  );

  var obj = executeActionGet(ref).getObjectValue(
    stringIDToTypeID("smartObjectMore")
  );

  var _tmp = obj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("size"));

  return {
    width: _tmp.getDouble(stringIDToTypeID("width")),
    height: _tmp.getDouble(stringIDToTypeID("height")),
  };
}
```

You can then use these dimensions with the layer bounds to resize() up to 100%

Answer (score -1):

A couple things first...
I tweaked your script minimally to get it to do something, however, depending on what you want it may still be inadequate. You say you want to "reset scale of Smart Object to 100%." The approach you are taking does not do that. What you (almost) completed was a script that changes the layers on the screen to a percentage of their CURRENT size. Assuming this is what you intend, all is good.

Next, one reason your code wasn't working is because you reference `layer` on line 8. You never (from the code you posted) created a variable called `layer` meaning the compiler has no idea what to do with that code. Actualy by simply deleting the two if statements in the beginning of your code, it will run.

Here is "working" code:

```
#target photoshop
try {
  var doc = app.activeDocument;

  var layers = doc.artLayers;

  var size = dialog();

  var defaultRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
  app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PERCENT;


  for (var i = 0; i < doc.artLayers.length -1; i++) {

    var activeLayer = doc.artLayers.getByName(doc.artLayers[i].name);

    var orUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;

    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PERCENT;

    activeLayer.resize(size, size, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);

    app.preferences.rulerUnits = orUnits;

  }


} catch (e) {
  // alert( e );
}


function dialog() {

  // Dialog box...
  var myWindow = new Window("dialog", "Resize Each Layer");

  // Keeps things inline
  myWindow.orientation = "row";

  // Informational text
  myWindow.add("statictext", undefined, "New size ( percentage ):");

  // This is the box where the size is inserted
  var myText = myWindow.add("edittext", undefined, "");
  myText.characters = 5;
  myText.active = true;

  // Ok....
  myWindow.add("button", undefined, "OK");
  if (myWindow.show() == 1) return myText.text;

}
```

Also, this code currently does not check for layer type, so problems will arise. Your next best step to account for this would probably be to add layer-checking INSIDE your for loop so that your script checks the layer within your `layers` array.

I also added the `doc.artLayers.length -1` to your for loop so that it would not try to resize the background layer. You should remove that "`-1`" once you add layer-checking. Let me know if I can further clarify anything for you.

Comment: I tried running the code you posted but it doesn't do anything. It's back to the same results as before with no errors being thrown. I edited my post with the current code.

Comment: Very bizarre.. may I ask how you run your code? Do you just save as .js and double-click? Or do you have Adobe ExtendScript?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I actually just tried running it with and without `#target photoshop` in the first line and the script would only run when it was there, my apologies. I will add it to the first line of my code above in the asnwer.

Comment: I'm running it as a .jsx through the browse menu through Photoshop. I was waiting to install it to the scripts folder until the kinks were ironed out. Running it as a .js or .jsx with the #target photoshop and without does nothing. And you don't need the #target photoshop if you are running it through Photoshop itself.

Comment: That's what I initially thought about the `#target photoshop`... I'm not sure what could be causing the issue then because I can get the script running just fine. While I poke around at the script, would you try running this line as its own script? `alert ("Scritps can run!", "Test", false);`

Comment: The script runs fine and performs Free Transform but nothing actually happens to the shapes. The sample code to print scripts can run also works fine.

Comment: Ohhh. So in order to use the script currently, try this: open a new psd, create 3 or so different colored smart objects using the rectangle tool (U), and then run the script. First try entering a value like 50. This should result in each object being resized to 50% of its current size. Next try the script again (you dont have to undo anything in your psd) and try typing 150. This should result in objects 2.5 times their old size.